# Как отключить позицию скролла после перезагрузки?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Если к примеру я пролистываю к середине страница и обновляю ее, скролл остается на той же позиции. Можно убрать что бы при перезагрузке автоматически пользователь был в начале странице?

Comment: Через js можно.

Comment: По-моему, никак. Можно при загрузке страницы делать `window.scrollTo(0,0)`, а чтобы не было видно рывка, изначально делать `body` прозрачным и через некоторое время убирать эту прозрачность...или сделать элемент-шторку и потом скрывать его.

Comment: Вёрстка только за внешний вид отвечает. Рутинг и позиция при перезагрузке не в её компетенции)